# Sublime text - Tab remap

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

Is there a way to change `Tab` to a different key to trigger snippets in Sublime Text? As an analouge, in Vim I would re-define the map leader from `\` to, say, `,`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit your Key Bindings (`Preferences → Key Bindgins - User`) (you can also search for `Key Bindings` in the command palette). And then add the following:

```
{
    "keys": ["the_shortcut_you_want"],
    "command": "insert_best_completion",
    "args":  {"default": "default_character", "exact": false}
}
```

The args are not mandatory if you don't want your shortcut to do anything if not used in a snippet context.

EDIT: I've been asked to provide a real example, apparently this was not enough.
So to use the provided, yet not so related example:

```
{
    "keys": [","],
    "command": "insert_best_completion",
    "args":  {"default": ",", "exact": false}
}
```

This should get the comma to trigger the snippets.
EDIT2: I can't test this right now, but I think that's exactly the kind of thing I tested. Mine was with a shortcut like `ctrl+shift+d`, so more like:

```
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+shift+d"],
    "command": "insert_best_completion",
}
```

Comment: Could you please write a concrete version of this general template for the situation described in the question? Thank you.

Comment: @paljenczy I would if there was said situation. The question is about how to be able to set another shortcut to trigger snippets. The OP never said which one he wanted to use. But for example, to use the vim example provided, that should be something like this:

    {
        "keys": [","],
        "command": "insert_best_completion",
        "args":  {"default": ",", "exact": false}
    }